# How to fetch and filter the data

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my backbone function, all works fine, even the filter. but the issue is, whenever i click on the filter type and switch to another filter type, it is filtering from the existing filtered data, instead of fetching new from server and filter...

in case if i add fetch call over my filter function, it fetch applying all data, without filtering... how can i fix this..?

my code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var school = {};

    school.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            name:'no name',
            age:'no age'
        }
    });

    school.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:school.model,
        url:'js/school.json',
        initialize:function(){
            this.sortVar = "name"
        }
    });

    school.view = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'div',
        className:'member',
        template:$('#newTemp').html(),
        render:function(){
            var temp = _.template(this.template);
            this.$el.html(temp(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    school.views = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#content'),
        events:{
            'click #newData' : 'newArrival',
            'click #showName' : 'showByName',
            'click #showAge' : 'showByAge'
        },
        initialize:function(){
            _.bindAll(this);
            this.collection = new school.collect;
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
            this.collection.fetch();
            this.childViews = [];
        },
        newArrival:function(){
            this.collection.fetch(); //it works fine, i use this for update
        },
        showByName:function(){
// this.collection.fetch(); //but i can't do this, it removes filtered data..
            this.sortVar = 'name';
            var filterType = _.filter(this.collection.models, function(item){
                return item.get('name') != '';
            })
            this.collection.reset(filterType); //resets without fetching (filtering  from existing datas..)
        },
        showByAge:function(){
// this.collection.fetch(); //but i can't do this, it removes filtered data..
            this.sortVar = 'age';
            var filterType = _.filter(this.collection.models,function(item){
                return item.get('age') != 0;
            })
            this.collection.reset(filterType); //resets without fetching (filtering from existing datas..)
        },
        render:function(){

            _.each(this.childViews, function(old){
                old.remove();    
            });

            this.childViews = [];

            var that = this;
            _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
                that.renderItem(item);    
            });
        },
        renderItem:function(item){
            var newItem = new school.view({model:item});
            this.$el.append(newItem.render().el);
            this.childViews.push(newItem);
        }
    });

    var newSchool = new school.views;
    });
```

thanks in advance, as well i do have another 2 methods to add which is sorting the name and age while show the datas.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Backbone, but it seems the issue is that the "school.collect" method is remembered. So if you don't re-execute that call to the school.json file, you still have the old data.

Comment: yes, but while i recall the json data, the filter doesn't works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is works for me.. thanks all.

```
showByAge:function(){
        var that = this;
        this.sortVar = 'age';
        this.collection.fetch()
        .done(function(){ // i am proceeding after i finish the fetch!
            var filterType = _.filter(that.collection.models,function(item){
                return item.get(that.sortVar) != 0;
            })
            that.collection.reset(filterType);
        })
    },
```

Comment: works for me save that the `fetch()` needs to be wrapped in a `$.when()`

Comment: This still involves fetching all the models initially via xhr, though, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only hack which is working, your technique is not crashing instead of doing models.where({status: 'active'}) when working with Obscura